# Pandas - Incrementally add to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add rows and columns to pandas incrementally. I have a lot of data stored across multiple datastores and a heuristic to determine a value. As I navigate across this datastore, I'd like to be able to incrementally update a dataframe, where in some cases, either names or days will be missing.

```
def foo():
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    year = 2016
    names = ['Bill', 'Bob', 'Ryan']
    for day in range(1, 4, 1):
        for name in names:
            if random.choice([True, False]):   # sometimes a name will be missing
                continue
            value = random.randrange(0, 20, 1) # random value from heuristic
            col = '{}_{}'.format(year, day)    # column name
            df = df.append({col: value, 'name': name}, ignore_index=True)
    df.set_index('name', inplace=True, drop=True)
    print(df.loc['Bill'])
```

This produces the following results:

```
      2016_1  2016_2  2016_3
name                        
Bill    15.0     NaN     NaN
Bill     NaN    12.0     NaN
```

I've created a heatmap of the data and it's blocky due to duplicate names, so the output I'm looking for is:

```
      2016_1  2016_2  2016_3
name                        
Bill    15.0    12.0     NaN
```

How can I combine these rows?

Is there a more efficient means of creating this dataframe?

Comment: What should happen if both 'Bill' rows have a value for a given column?

Comment: @Valentino Good question: For my application, this should never be a case as all names have a unique identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :-

```
df.groupby('name')[df.columns.values].sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
df.pivot_table(index='name', aggfunc='sum', dropna=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After you run your `foo()` function, you can use any aggregation function (if you have only one value per column and all the othes are null) and `groupby` on `df`.

First, use `reset_index` to get back your `name` column.
Then use `groupby` and `apply`. Here I propose a custom function which checks that there is only one value per column, and raise a `ValueError` if not.

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

def aggdata(x):
    if all([i <= 1 for i in x.count()]):
        return x.mean()
    else:
        raise ValueError

ddf = df.groupby('name').apply(aggdata)
```

If all the values of the column are null but one, `x.mean()` will return that value (actually, you can use almost any aggregator, since there is only one value, that is the one returned).

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to have the name as column and date as index instead. Plus, you can work within the loop with lists and afterwards create the pd.DataFrame.

e.g.

```
year = 2016
names = ['Bill', 'Bob', 'Ryan']

index = []
valueBill = []
valueBob = []
valueRyan = []

for day in range(1, 4):
    if random.choice([True, False]):   # sometimes a name will be missing
        valueBill.append(random.randrange(0, 20))
        valueBob.append(random.randrange(0, 90))
        valueRyan.append(random.randrange(0, 200)) 
        index.append('{}-0{}'.format(year, day))    # column name
    else:
        valueBill.append(np.nan)
        valueBob.append(np.nan)
        valueRyan.append(np.nan)
        index.append(np.nan)

df = pd.DataFrame({})

for name, value in zip(names,[valueBill,valueBob,valueRyan]):
    df[name] = value
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(index))
```

Comment: This would assume that I knew all of the names in advance, and create a list for each of them. I'm uncertain this approach is desirable.

Answer (score 0):

You can append the entries with new names if it does not already exist and then do an update to update existing entries.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

def foo():
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    year = 2016
    names = ['Bill', 'Bob', 'Ryan']
    for day in range(1, 4, 1):
        for name in names:
            if random.choice([True, False]):   # sometimes a name will be missing
                continue
            value = random.randrange(0, 20, 1) # random value from heuristic
            col = '{}_{}'.format(year, day)    # column name
            new_df = pd.DataFrame({col: value, 'name':name}, index=[1]).set_index('name')
            df = pd.concat([df,new_df[~new_df.index.isin(df.index)].dropna()])
            df.update(new_df)
    #df.set_index('name', inplace=True, drop=True)
    print(df)
```